# deserialize json model in model with marshmallow python

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I going to deserialize json model

```
class LogsSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Logs
        sqla_session = Session

class UsersSchema(ModelSchema):
    logs = fields.Nested(LogsSchema,exclude=('User', ))
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        sqla_session = Session
```

json model request

```
<QueryDict: {u'Username': [u'ramin world'], u'logs': [u'[UserLog=test]'], u'Date': [u'null'], u'Password': [u'1234'], u'Email': [u'ramin@blacat.gmail.com'], u'Name': [u'Farajpour']}>
```

load json request:

```
users_schema = UsersSchema()
json_dict = users_schema.load(usermodel,session=Session).data
```

result:

```
{'Username': u'ramin world', 'Password': u'1234', 'Name': u'Farajpour', 'Email': u'ramin@blacat.gmail.com'}
```

you see model `u'logs': [u'[UserLog=test]']` is not on result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `many=True`in logs:

```
class UsersSchema(ModelSchema):
    logs = fields.Nested(LogsSchema,exclude=('User', ), many=True)
    ...
```